# how do I get a 're-share' option to show up in my app's dialog.feed post

Tags: facebook, dialog, feed, share

I have a fb app that has an html anchor tag which uses href = http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed...

it works fine.

but when the post shows up in the feed, it only has a 'comment' and a 'like' option beneath it.

however, I see some other posts in my feed that also have a 'reshare' option.

how do I get that?

thanks,
Shannon

Answer (score 2):

I am having a similar problem; the user can post the photo to their own (or someone else's wall) but only the like and comment options appear with the post.

```
    FB.init({appId: "xxxxxxxxxxx", status: true, cookie: true});

    function fbShare(pic) {
        event.preventDefault();
         //call the API
         var obj = {
            method: 'feed',
            link: 'http://localhost/users/#/gingles/1680/',
            picture: 'http://c711249.r49.cf2.rackcdn.com/thumbs/1680_19.png',
            name: 'gingle social transparancy',
            caption: __video.title,
            redirect_uri: 'http://www.gingle.tv/close-page',
            description: 'Watch this video on gingle.tv',
        };

        function callback(response) {
         console.log(response);
       }

       FB.ui(obj, callback);
    }
```

The option to post comes up just fine

But once posted, no share option exists
(screenshots were filtered out by my newness to this site)

I have spend quite a while pouring through the facebook documentation but I can't see a solution.

To make this more fun, when using the URL method, I was getting a share option, but the photo would be lost. but after all my experiments with the FB.ui rolling back to the URL approach will not share.

```
    var fbUrl = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=xxxxxxxxxxx&' +
        'link=http://' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.host + '/users/#/' + __video.username + '/' + __video.id) + '&picture=' + $(this).find('img').attr('src') +
        '&name=gingle%20|%20social%20transparency&' + 'caption=' + __video.title +  
        '&description=Watch%20this%20ideo%20on%20gingle.tv&' +  
        'redirect_uri=http://www.gingle.tv/close-page';

    $('#screenshot_social').html('<a href="' + fbUrl + '" target=_blank>Share on Facebook</a>');
```

Any direction or ideas would be most welcome.

Comment: Technically this was another question, trying to build upon the original with more details. Apologies to anyone reading it hoping for the answer.

Comment: If it makes a difference, myapp is a non-canvas app.

Meanwhile I did find a workaround, though it is clunky: make an action using my URL posting approach as the link. The redirect_uri makes this a bit messy, though.